# Get tab name onclick in salesforce1

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app

I am developing an application of salesforce1 using Visual-Force for iOS(iPad), I want to get Tab menu name when click on this, it is possible? If possible then how can we get the tab name please help me.

[image]

Comment: Any code you tried?

Comment: Yes, I have already answered and provide code also. You can see bellow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible.  Custom tabs can point to lightning components but one cannot intercept standard tab clicks.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/44276)

Comment: Sorry, but 1st question was is this possible.. My answer I do not think it is possible.. That is my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I find it, Use following code.

```
  public string myTab{set;get;}
  public String currentApp {get;private set;}
  public String allTabsDebug {get; private set;}
  public String currentTab {get; private set;}
  public String currentTabDebug {get; private set;}
  public testJsonToKnockout()
  {
     String tabId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('sfdc.tabName');  
    for(Schema.DescribeTabSetResult dtsr : Schema.describeTabs()) {
            if(dtsr.isSelected()) {
                currentApp = dtsr.label;
                allTabsDebug = JSON.serializePretty(dtsr.tabs);
                if(String.isNotBlank(tabId)){
                    for(Schema.DescribeTabResult dtr : dtsr.tabs){
                        if(String.isNotBlank(dtr.url) && dtr.url.contains(tabId)){
                            myTab = dtr.label;
                            //currentTabDebug = JSON.serializePretty(dtr);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;   
            }           
        }

    }
```